# Flip a Button control like an Image using FlowDirection property

Tags: wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wpf-controls, wpf-4.0

In WPF is it possible to Flip a Button like an Image is being flipped when we set FlowDirection proerty to "RightToLeft" ?

Screenshot of my requirement: 
[image]

My requirement may be new. But I need it. Any Suggestions plz...

Basically this can be achieved using Button's RenderTransform's ScaleX = -1. But it will change the actual position of Button in window. I need to display the button in flipped manner in the same place where it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could set the `RenderTransform` property in a Style Trigger:

```
<Button Content="Update" FlowDirection="LeftToRight">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="RenderTransformOrigin" Value="0.5,0.5"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="FlowDirection" Value="LeftToRight">
                    <Setter Property="RenderTransform">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <ScaleTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the [RenderTransformOrigin](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980041%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).  This will make the flip stay in place.  Right now,it's flipping on the default origin of 0,0.  If you set it to .5/.5, it will flip from the center.